# Underlying provider failed to open when I convert database property to do not copy

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

This is the connection string and when I change the property of the database file (`database1.mdf`) to "do not copy", it causes an error.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf` that you can't *not copy* the database to the DataDirectory.

The connection string tries to find and attach the database from the given address and it can't find it. you can attach the db first and then use this connection strings:

```
<add provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;
    initial catalog=Database1;
    integrated security=True;/>
```